# Reversing ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How can I reverse ObservableCollection in c#?

```
collection = new ObservableCollection<type>(collection.Reverse());
```

is not working for me. I search internet but unexpectedly I didn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reverse() does not return anything, you cannot use the reverse function directly, you could do something like this,

Example,

```
 ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            User uo = new User();
            uo.ID = i;
            uo.Name = i.ToString();
            users.Add(uo);


        }
        List<User> reversed = getResult(users);
        ObservableCollection<User> result = new ObservableCollection<User>(reversed);
    }

    private List<User> getResult(ObservableCollection<User> res)
    {
        List<User> result = res.ToList();
        result.Reverse();
        return result;
    }
    public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: i'm getting an error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<type>.ObservableCollection(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<type>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: check the modified answer